# Ratings based user similarity algorithm example

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering

I am building a recommendation engine and trying to overcome the new user problem. I want to ask new users to rate a select number of items then find out what other users they are most similar to. Then by use the data from the similar users to generate the initial recommendations.

I am not certain how to do this as I have previously worked on item-to-item recommendations. Does anyone have an example of this? Either some pseudo-code or an implementation in any language (preferably not a functional language).

I think I am looking for a user based nearest neighbour algorithm but not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The cold-start problem is not specified to an implementation based on user-user similarity. How did you solve this in your item-item similarity-based implementation?

You have already suggested one approach: make the user give you data. If that's feasible, that's a great answer. Ideally, you choose items that are diverse -- not very similar amongst themselves.

It's not so wrong to show a simple top-10 list as recommendations before you have any data, and then start recommending as best you can from the moment you have 1 data point. That's the "normal" way to me.

Comment: I haven't solved the item-item cold start problem. Currently the majority of recommendations is done using a matrix of all the items with a counter of the number of times any of the users have liked any two items. For example if userA likes item1, item2 and item3 and userB likes item1 and item3 the matrix looks like (item1, item2) 1, (item1, item3) 2 etc. For the new user recommendations I want to use user-user rating similarity because I think the recommendations will be more relevant. If they aren't I learnt something new :)

Comment: OK. Your co-occurrence counts are not going to help you compute user-user similarity though. For that you'd really need user-user cooccurrence. But that's a tangent. I think the best answer for you is to compute recommendations from the first rating you have, and to show a top-10 list when you have no ratings.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have gone for asking users to rate products when they first signup to the site. Then identify similar users for the initial recommendations until I can use the co-occurrence counts. I will paste the code below.

Answer (score 1):

This can be framed as an active learning problem. [Karimi, Freudenthaler, Nanopoulos, and Schmidt-Thieme (2011)](http://www.ismll.uni-hildesheim.de/pub/pdfs/karimi-ictai.pdf) give one way to deal with it in a matrix factorization setting, but IMO there are a ton of problems with their approach (and I happen to be working on a better way, though for now it's too slow to be usable).

The basic question is: what items will tell me the most about this new user's preferences? Without knowing the specifics of your recommendation engine, it's hard to say more than to pick a few relatively diverse items that users are likely to have opinions on (e.g. popular movies from different genres).

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I am going to ask users when the first sign up to rate a number of diverse items to identify similar users for the initial recommendations. I will paste the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first attempt the solve this problem. I ask all new users to rate a number of diverse products. Then I identify the 3 existing users they are most similar to based on these ratings. Then I can use the information I have on these three users to recommend the items the first time they visit the site.

Thanks to everyone who gave me advice :)

```
/**

     * Select all of the customer ratings
     */

$rows = getRows("SELECT * FROM customer_ratings;", 'NUM');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //Fill distanse array to zero for all items
    $distance = array_fill(0, count($rows), 0);

    $instance = $_POST['instance'];


    //Loop over each of the exisiting ratings rows
    for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
        //Loop over the 5 items (The first two are id and name we only need 2-6)
        for($j = 2; $j < 7; $j++) {
                $distance[$i] += abs(($rows[$i][$j] - $instance[$j]));
        }
    }

    //Sort distances by ascending order
    asort($distance);

    $distanceCopy = $distance;

    $stringBuff = "";

    //Select the three most similar
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        $maxs = array_keys($distanceCopy, min($distanceCopy));
        $stringBuff = $stringBuff . " ". ($maxs[0]+1) .",";
        unset($distanceCopy[$maxs[0]]);
    }

    $stringBuff = substr_replace($stringBuff,"", -1);

    echo "String buff: ".$stringBuff;

    $mostSimilar = getRows("SELECT name FROM customer_ratings WHERE id IN ($stringBuff);", 'NUM');

}
```